# While loop (check if the input from the keyboard is not an int, then keep asking until an int will be inserted)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

trying to check if the input from the keyboard is not an int, then keep asking until an int will be inserted. any suggestions?

this is my piece of code(the catch part if the user will insert anything but int in the input stream):

this is my try/catch block....any other way to make it work and short!
thank you in advance

```
                //thinking about using : while(!myscanner.hasNextInt())

            try
            {
                myinput = myscanner.nextInt();
                while(myinput > MAXARRAY || myinput < 0 || (myinput != (int)myinput))
                {   
                    System.out.print("Size must be from 0 - 15. Please reenter: ");
                    myinput = myscanner.nextInt();
                }
            }catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                while(myinput > MAXARRAY || myinput < 0 || (myinput != (int)myinput))
                {
                System.out.println("Size must be from 0 - 15. Please reenter: ");
                myinput = myscanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
```

Comment: `myinput != (int)myinput` can never be true if `myinput` is of type `int`.

Comment: more explanation please or an example....thank you

Comment: How about *you* explain your intention first.

Comment: trying to force the user to enter an int between 0 and 15.....and if the user is keep inserting anything out of that range or any other data type......he will be asked to reenter the value in the scanner until the condition is met

Comment: That much I understood. But your code has little in common with your requirements.

Comment: So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with single `while` loop, e.g.:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Enter an int value");
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int token = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(token);
        break;
    }else {
        scanner.nextLine();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The snippet you sent me, I am a biginner, and I do understand it but I am trying to eliminate using strings....I think I know what is the outcome of you're snippet....... I'll execute it and see if my assumption is right :)

Answer (score 0):

### Below code can used to solve it using the regular expressions for desired input.

```
    BufferedReader dataInputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = null;
    Integer number = null;
    //Below pattern says 0-15
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]|1[0-5]");
       while(input==null || !pattern.matcher(input).matches()){
           System.out.print("Enter number: ");
           input = dataInputReader.readLine();
           if(pattern.matcher(input).matches()){
               number = Integer.parseInt(input);
           }else{
               System.out.println("Size must be from 0 - 15. Please reenter: ");

           }

       }
       System.out.println("Input number is: "+number);
```